# Updating an array using 2 different process using MPI

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am trying to update an array `int arr[2]` using 2 processes, where the first index will be filled by process 1 and the second index will be filled by process 2. I have written the following code for the same

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[2];
      
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    int myrank, size; //size will take care of number of processes 
    
    
    
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank) ;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    
    if(myrank==0)
    arr[0]=1;
    
    if(myrank==1)
    arr[1]=2;
    
     MPI_Finalize();
    
    printf("%d %d\n",arr[0],arr[1]);
    
    
    return 0;
        
        
}
```

As expected the output is

```
0 2
1 0
```

Or sometimes (when process 1 reaches the print statement first)

```
1 0
0 2
```

My question is, I have declared the array outside `MPI_Init`  and I am printing the array after `MPI_Finalize()`, then why both the processes are printing? And is there any way to store the output

```
1 2
```

in the array without actually sending the data from one process to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, I have declared the array outside MPI_Init and I am
> printing the array after MPI_Finalize(), then why both the processes
> are printing?

From [MPT_INIT](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Init.html) one can read:

> **The MPI standard does not say what a program can do before an MPI_INIT
> or after an MPI_FINALIZE.** In the MPICH implementation, you should do
> as little as possible. In particular, avoid anything that changes the
> external state of the program, such as opening files, reading standard
> input or writing to standard output.

and from [MPI_FINALIZE](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Finalize.html):

> All processes must call this routine before exiting. **The number of
> processes running after this routine is called is undefined;** it is
> best not to perform much more than a return rc after calling
> MPI_Finalize.

and :

> **The MPI standard requires that MPI_Finalize be called only by the same
> thread that initialized MPI with either MPI_Init or MPI_Init_thread.**

So in your specific case all processes are allocation the array and print it.

> And is there any way to store the output 1 2  in the array without
> actually sending the data from one process to another?

There is no processing sending the message between each other. What is happening (very informally) is that MPI starts a complete copy of your program *per* process, including also the allocation of the array `int arr[2];`.

If you want to have only one process allocation it, let us say the process with rank = 0 then do:

```
...
if(myrank == 0){
 
   int arr[2];
}
```

I personally prefer to do the following, declare a pointer:

```
int *arr = NULL;
```

and the allocate it only on the process that needs it:

```
if(myrank == 0){
  arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
  ...
}
```